# Click event for SVG rectangle

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm using SVG together with jQuery in my Mvc Application. I draw a series of rectangles on my page and what I would like to do is attach a click or mouseover event for each rectangle, for say, popup an alert box.
I've tried something like this, so far:

```
$("rect[id='Y6']").attr('onclick', function() { alert("Hello!") });
```

and

```
$("rect[id='Y6']").live('click', function() {    
    alert("Hello!");
};
```

But sadly none of this events really worked for this control.
Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

I'm adding the javascript code I'm using below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*function resetSize(svg, width, height) {
        svg.configure({ width: width || $(svg._container).width(),
            height: height || $(svg._container).height()
        });
    }*/
    function onLoad(svg, error) {
        //svg.text(10, 20, error || 'Loaded into ' + this.id);
        //resetSize(svg, null, null); //'100%', '100%');
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#layout').svg({});

        var svg = $('#layout').svg('get');
        svg.load('<%= Url.Action("Layout", new{ id = Model.Id }) %>', { //<%= Url.Content("~/media/svg/lion.xml") %>', {
            addTo: false,
            changeSize: false,
            onLoad: onLoad
        });
    });    

$('rect#Y6').click( function(){
  alert('hello');
});

</script>
```

The rectangles are loaded from a svg picture.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code to add the `click` handler needs to be part of the `onLoad` function - with that change [it works for me](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/load-svg.html).

Comment: Thanks Robert, after trying to write as you suggested, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For others, I was struggling with a mobile click event and it works with `$(document).on('click touch', '.button', function () { ... });`

Comment: Discrimination against triangles that is.

Comment: if you put the script as last element of body then it shoud work to

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('rect#Y6').click( function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: It didn't work either, Ken. I appreciate the help though. The control was rendered like this:  <rect style="fill:black;fill-opacity:0.78488375;stroke:black;stroke-width:0.04082483;stroke-miterlimit:1;stroke-opacity:0.78488375;stroke-dasharray:none" id="Y6" width="20" height="20" x="120.44141" y="32.362183" class="wz-flat" label=""></rect>

Comment: Now, that's quite strange. Using firebug, I notice that when I'm loading the page, it enters the click event correctly. But upon clicking the rectangle, nothing really happens and the event is never fired. Do you have any clue? EDIT: If you want to see my jquery code or know any details about my files, I will add them in my comment.

Comment: @Hallaghan, sure. Without the code it's hard to say what's going wrong.