# attach events to SVG paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a SVG map in my html with the `<svg>` tag. and I want to attach events so I can click them and trigger some events. I know I can attach click event using jQuery on polygon elements. But some areas in this map are made using paths and I'd like to trigger some events when I click inside the paths, not on the paths.

What's the way to do that? Using jQuery is preferred.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053991/click-event-for-svg-rectangle

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo to work with.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you `fill` a `<path>` then clicking inside it (on the fill) will trigger the event handler:

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmsrP/1/

```xml
<path id="sauce" fill="#f00" … />
```

```js
$('#sauce').on('click',function(){ … });
```

You can choose to explicitly fill the path with the color `transparent` and mouse events will still be caught:

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmsrP/2/

```xml
<path fill="transparent" … />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with Opera 12.12.. it fills the path with black :(

Comment: As it turns out though, you can set fill-opacity to 0, and be good to go!

Comment: This solution does not provide for accessibility or keyboard navigation.

Comment: If you wrap the path in an anchor tag, it will be accessible: http://jsfiddle.net/TmsrP/489/

Comment: On [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543287/detect-click-inside-svg-path-using-angularjs) a FireFox developer pointed out that `fill="transparent"`  is forcing the browser to render the fill (which happens to be transparent) when all you want is to detect a mouse over for which the pointer-events property is specifically designed.  I solved it with `fill="none"` and `<style> path { pointer-events: visibleFill } </style>`

Comment: For people who don't want jquery: document.getElementById("mypath").addEventListener('click', event => { });