# Custom Javascript Alert Popup onclick svg path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, path, popup

I have embedded an svg file into an html file and can view it in all browsers and platforms. I now want to make specific paths within the svg clickable. I have used an onclick event to perform this function, however, I have only been able to get a javascript alert box to popup when the path is clicked. Instead of the default javascript alert, I need a custom popup which I can then include unique custom text and a hyperlink url for each of the paths. Therefore, each path would have its own text and hyperlink.

Does anyone know the best/easiest way to accomplish this?

Excerpts from my code below:

```
<script>
function notify(evt){alert(evt.target.id)}
</script>

<style>
path:hover {
fill: #456353; opacity: .5
}
</style>


<svg version="1.1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="771.429px" height="986.584px" viewBox="0 0 771.429 986.584" enable-background="new 0 0 771.429 986.584"
 xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Base_map" display="none">
<g id="ahf8dJ.tif" display="inline">

<path onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="Plot1" fill="#BDD5CC" stroke="#939598" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M585.308,538.849l68.457,19.287l-0.662,6.611
    l14.383,3.473l3.637,6.115l-7.439,24.797l52.404,22.814l3.307-4.795c0,0-6.613-1.322-12.729-4.793
    c-6.117-3.473-11.076-11.076-16.037-19.176c-4.959-8.102-11.406-24.303-13.885-30.748c-2.48-6.447-9.313-8.322-15.484-11.518
    s-6.725-4.848-8.816-8.928c-2.094-4.076-5.182-0.77-9.479,2.756c-4.299,3.527-14.658,0.332-18.734-0.66
    c-4.078-0.992-13.006-3.197-19.838-3.748c-6.622-0.534-11.512-2.177-18.828-4.151L585.308,538.849z" />

<path onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="Plot2" fill="#BDD5CC" stroke="#939598" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M668.644,531.851
    c1.652,5.621,2.645,10.084,3.305,12.729c0.662,2.645,0.662,5.125-1.652,5.291s-7.439-1.984-10.912-5.455
    c-3.471-3.473-4.133-5.457-3.305-13.061c0.826-7.604,0.992-13.061,4.133-13.887s5.125,3.141,5.951,5.951
    S668.644,531.851,668.644,531.851z"/>

<path onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="Plot3" fill="#BDD5CC" stroke="#939598" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M520.358,495.1c9.752,1.487,25.291,6.499,32.4,8.152
    c7.107,1.653,20.168-1.323,27.938-3.637c7.77-2.314,9.424-0.496,12.068,1.653c2.645,2.148,6.281,6.446,9.918,11.241
    s1.322,7.604-0.496,11.572c-1.818,3.967,0.992,3.967,4.959,6.117c3.969,2.148,4.959-1.324,7.439-4.133
    c2.48-2.811,6.117-2.48,9.754-0.662s6.447,7.936,9.422,12.068c2.977,4.133,4.133,3.471,11.242-0.166s9.422-15.539,9.422-20.168
    s1.158-8.1,3.141-9.092c1.984-0.991,1.984-2.976,1.158-6.944c-0.014-0.066-0.315-1.538-0.332-1.612l-2.634,2.961
    c-5.442,5.389-9.572,2.361-9.572,2.361c-3.515-1.625-5.985-2.104-5.985-2.104c-2.828-0.583-2.688-3.301-2.688-3.301
    c-1.438-4.905-4.737-1.592-4.737-1.592c-5.55,6.503-23.852-2.333-23.852-2.333c-8.073,14.763-13.349,2.333-13.349,2.333
    c-3.5-8.372-13.794-5.053-13.794-5.053c-29.848,9.112-39.272,4.207-39.272,4.207l-19.986-5.606L520.358,495.1z"/>

<path onclick="top.notify(evt)" id="Plot4" fill="#BDD5CC" stroke="#939598" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M626.487,533.173c3.307,4.465,4.299,6.943,1.322,6.777
    c-2.975-0.164-16.695-1.982-25.953-3.637c-9.258-1.652-18.846-4.959-29.426-7.439c-10.58-2.479-15.209-4.297-17.523-5.289
    s-4.463-3.141,0.496-3.803c4.959-0.66,14.879,0.662,18.35,1.984s16.035,5.125,19.672,6.447s12.398,5.291,15.705,5.125
    s6.117-2.148,7.439-3.803c1.322-1.652,5.125-2.977,6.281-1.322C624.009,529.867,626.487,533.173,626.487,533.173z"/>
```

Comment: Since you managed to trigger your event from SVG, is your question simply how to open a popup window in JavaScript?

Comment: yes...to an extent, however, it needs to be a custom popup window that I can include individual hyperlinks based on specific paths that are clicked. For instance, when you click "Path 1" a popup appears with a url and text specific to "Path 1" and so on...

Comment: You only have one path in your SVG, so in this scenario that path will always be the one that triggers the popup and ends up being your `evt.target`. If you want more than just the target element, but what to know where specifically the user clicked, the event has properties for that (e.g. `clientX` and `clientY`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701461/attach-events-to-svg-paths.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that I only included excerpts from the code. I actually have dozens of clickable paths. id="Plot1", id="Plot2", id="Plot3", etc. The overall problem that I run into is that the javascript alert is not customizable. I can only include unformatted text (whatever text I put in as the id).

Comment: So the question is not about how to get values from the SVG, but how to open a popup from JavaScript? Look at `window.open`. Some examples: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351771/open-popup-window-using-javascript

Comment: Yes, the real question is how I can get a custom, unique, alert box to appear when a path is clicked and within that box will be a unique url specific to the path that is clicked. The piece I am stuck on is how to include that within the svg path so that the script will know which path should have which url. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom attribute to each of your paths to store the URL you want to open:

```
<path d="M10,60 L50,10 90,60" data-url="http://www.google.com/" />
```

Then access this URL in your event handler:

```
var url = evt.target.getAttribute('data-url');
```

Then open a popup window with that URL:

```
window.open(url);
```

So the complete script becomes:

```
function notify(evt){
    var url = evt.target.getAttribute('data-url');
    window.open(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right in that your need is for something like alert("xxx") which can contain any HTML...

There's 3 parts: a style, a div and a function to show the popup

```
<style>
  #popupInfo
  {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(20,20,20,0.3);
  }
  #closeButton
  {
      position: absolute;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background: transparent url(X_light.gif);
      right: 5px;
      top: 5px;
  }
  #closeButton:hover
  {
      background: url(X_dark.gif);
      z-index: 99;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="popupInfo"">
      <div id="closeButton" onclick="document.getElementById('popupInfo').style.visibility = 'hidden';"></div>
      <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr style="height:32px;"><td ></td></tr>
      <tr><td id="popupInfoText"></td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function popupInfo(newtext, width, height){
        var popStyle= document.getElementById("popupInfo").style
        if( width ) popStyle.width=width.toString()+'px';
        if( height ) popStyle.height=height.toString()+'px';
        document.getElementById("popupInfoText").innerHTML = newtext;
        popStyle.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```

The "X_light.gif" and "X_dark.gif" are 32x32pixel grey X's on transparent used as the Close button.

A call to e.g. `popupInfo("<H1>Alert!</H1>This is a message!");` will show the message.
To get an html document from a file you could do it several ways, if they are fixed files then you could:

```
popupInfo("<IFRAME src='message.html'></IFRAME>");
```

where `message.html` is like:

```
<H1>Hello there!</H1>
<p>This is a test message</p>
```

The result being:
...a nice image that I can't post as a guest :(

Enjoy!
TonyWilk