# Detect click inside SVG <path> using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701461/attach-events-to-svg-paths) shows how to do it with Jquery, but I can't get it to work in AagularJs.

I have an SVG image containing several areas delineated by `<path>`s, and want ti detect which one is clicked.

The paths are declared as

```
   <path id="inner" fill="transparent"  ng-click='innerRoomClicked'
        stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 132.00,249.00
           C 132.00,249.00 132.00,348.00 132.00,348.00
             132.00,348.00 180.00,348.00 180.00,348.00
```

etc

and

```
  <path id="A B C"
        fill="transparent"  ng-click='innerRoomClicked' stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 171.06,307.00
           C 171.06,307.00 167.06,307.00 167.06,307.00
             167.06,307.00 169.00,301.94 169.00,301.94
             169.00,301.94 171.06,307.00 171.06,307.00 Z
```

etc

and, in the controller,

```
$scope.outerRoomClicked = function()
{
    alert('outerRoomClicked');
}

$scope.innerRoomClicked = function()
{
    alert('innerRoomClicked');
}
```

BUT, neither of those are called.  What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: using fill="transparent" is bad, use the pointer-events property instead, it's much more efficient.

Comment: can you point me to some more info?

Comment: "the pointer-events property instead" and why transparent fill, as recommended in the other question, is bad

Comment: I am a Firefox developer. You're forcing the browser to render the fill (which happens to be transparent) when all you want is to detect a mouse over for which the pointer-events property is specifically designed.

Comment: Thanks. I will go Google the pointer-events property

Comment: Sorry, can you help? I removed the `fill="transparent"` and added `<path style="pointer-events: visiblePainted"`, but without a `fill` my SVG renders as a black rectangle.

Comment: you want fill="none"

Comment: Solved. Changes fill to none & added `<style>
   path  {
    pointer-events: visibleFill   
   }
   </style>`  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ng-click='innerRoomClicked' to ng-click='innerRoomClicked()'

Comment: Lolx! It has been along, hard day, and I overlooked such a n00b mistake. Thanks!