# Get IE 8 SVG Web elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, internet-explorer-8, svgweb

I'm loading a svg to my web page different depending of wich browser it is. The problem is that in IE i can't get the svg elements since it is loaded differently.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
    <div id="SVGContainer"></div>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <object id="infoobjectgraph" src="@routes.Assets.at(graphfilename)" classid="image/svg+xml" width="800" height="600" >
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <object id="infoobjectgraph" data="@routes.Assets.at(graphfilename)" type="image/svg+xml" width="800" height="600" >
<![endif]-->
```

If it's not IE, i'll just use `$("#SVGContainer").on("click", "g.node a", function(event){...}`, and it works great. How can I do the same with IE?

I've tried `$("#infoobjectgraph").on("click", "g", function(event){...}` but this doesn't work.

The reason I load the svg differently is that I'm using SVG Web, so that svg works in IE8. So the loading thing has to be as it is. So for IE it is loaded as an object, and for !IE, I load all the contents from the svg and put it in #SVGContainer.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
"g" is a node in my svg. For example:

```
<svg>
<g id="node1" class="node">
...
</g>
<g id="node2" class="node">
...
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What is "g" - surely it needs to be similar to the event binding above, e.g. attaching to an anchor or clickable element. Not sure if the object tag supports events either, which could also be preventing it working.

Comment: "g" is a node in my svg. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, so I think it's the lack of support for being able to handle click events on those tags with jQuery - have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053991/click-event-for-svg-rectangle - alternatively - if you have g.node a in IE as well as !IE then you should be able to use that same parameter?

Comment: I don't think the svg is loaded in the DOM tree in IE, and therefore it seems that I can not get it in the same way.