# Unable to click on svg element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am trying to click on `svg` element using jQuery, but it does not trigger the click.

`$('#hvkxtbgbpikc-upgrade-modal').click();`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053991/click-event-for-svg-rectangle)

Comment: I think this is same :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472224/add-onclick-event-to-svg-element

Comment: Try specifying a ref for the svg element ,you can use this as a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093760/in-react-js-is-there-any-function-similar-like-document-getelementbyid-in-ja/38093981#38093981 and then `$(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refName)).click();`